# What happens to heap memory after deallocation?

Tags: assembly, memory-management, heap-memory, masm

I'm trying to write an assembly program using MASM. I use GetProcessHeap to get the heap, and HeapAlloc and HeapFree to allocate and free heap memory chunks. I'm wondering what happens to memory locations when they are freed, supposing that the memory location hasn't been HeapAlloc'd again? Do they keep their old values, or do they get overwritten without my knowledge?

Also, can I access the freed memory locations?

Comment: As [msdn says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366701.aspx): "You should not refer in any way to memory that has been freed by HeapFree."  If you do that all bets are off.

Comment: I cant imagine they would burn the bandwidth to clear or modify that memory when freed.  But that still doesnt mean you should mess with it...as already stated all bets are off...

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by Jester, it's not safe to access the memory after its been freed. Anything could happen to that memory. In particular the heap manager may use it for its own purposes, or it may decommit the pages in order to return the memory to the OS. In later case trying to access that memory will cause your program to crash. Since you're talking about the default heap, it's also possible for Windows or third-party DLLs to allocate that memory, possibly asynchronously from thread you didn't create.